# Turn on PC but no Signal to monitor

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building

I am familiar with building PC's doing that already 20 years for me and friends and everyone. But now i am totally stuck with mine.
One day I wanted to turn on my PC and I realized, that the fans were moving shortly only and then stopped for a second just to start again rotating. No signal was shown on monitor. So I did remove all party I didn't need need to boot up like instead of my 4 RAM sticks I used just one and removed all extra HDD. Nothing changed. So I switched Memory to a different slot. This time the pc starts, all fans moving, no stoppage as before but still no monitor, its still blinking waiting for signal. (couldn't try onboard graphics, since I don't have one). I tried to replug both of my screens using different cables. (hdmi+dp)
Purchased one new RAM hoping that it's not the motherboard. No change, tested all 8 slots.
Now I bought a new CPU (Ryzen 9) and a new Motherboard (ASUS Prime X570-PRO). Installed everything. So I only have my old graphics card, power supply and hdd/ssd. Since I went for a new Case as well I also got new sata cables. The new motherboard as well has an HDMI + Diplay Port support.
I was 100% sure it will work, but somehow I still get the same result. No signal to my monitor. So I thought it must be the hdd or ssd and removed both. removed graphics card. So I have a 100% new setup besides power supply. But still no signal. I am a bit surprised now, my computer should boot without HDD and at least complain that there is no boot chance...
Now I will create a win 10 Bootstick/installer to try out booting from USB. 
What else am I missing?
I am really frustrated, ok i am not, but I am surprised that it is still not working.... 
Any help is upvoted.

Comment: Few possibilities. There's a small possibility that the new board X570 might need BIOS update before it can detect Ryzen 9 CPU. Check Asus website for details under Support section for this board. Your PSU might not be providing adequate power to the system. Re-seat all components. Reset CMOS  and try again.

Comment: I thought about bios update as well but all x570 do support ryzen9 out of the box. About the power I do have enough. I will reset cmos next. Have done that on old board. Will try with new one soon

Comment: don't bother with bootable sticks etc. you should be able to get a signal and get into the BIOS without any bootable media

Comment: is the power supply any good?

Comment: Nope it was broken ;)